# QBUsers.signOut not working in android quickblox sdk

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on signout user in quickblox but the below code is not working without any error:

```
QBUsers.signOut();
```

I searched its documentation as well and I got one below code for signout:

```
QBUsers.signOut(new QBEntityCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

            }
        });
```

This one is giving me an error that: 
Class

> 'Anonymous class derived from QBEntityCallBack' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onSuccess(T, Bundle)' in 'QBEntityCallBack'

My app level gradle links:

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.0'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0'
```

My project level gradle link:

```
maven {
    url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
}
```

I just want to sign out my current user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn()) {

        QBChatService.getInstance().logout(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });
}
```